# Jax-rs / Jersey inter-thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, jax-rs

Is there a way to make the handling threads in Jax-rs / Jersey communicate between them?
If so, what would be the best way?

Comment: Why oh why would you want to do this?

Comment: haha Perception :) I would like to send a response to client1 that depends on weather another HTTP request comes from client2 during a time-interval after that I received the request from client1.
I thought that I could make the client1 thread wait for a while and be notified by another thread that a similar HTTP request has arrived. Any suggestions on another way to do it?

Comment: That's not a good use case for JAX-RS. Have you taken a look at Comet/Long polling?

Comment: There's nothing specific to JAX-RS here.  Read about the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package and its subpackages; a [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) is probably what you want.

Comment: That's sounds like a really bad idea.  Why not have client1 poll the server after a certain amount of time to see if there was a request from client2?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad design. 
Each request-response should be autonomous as possible. 
If you need inter-thread communications, 
You can use standard j2se stuff, 
For example, some synchronized data structure ,  and you can select one from
the [java.util.concurrent](http://ricardozuasti.com/2012/java-concurrency-examples-getting-feedback-from-concurrent-tasks/) package. 
You can have for example a singleton that can be accessed via its static getInstance method from all the threads, and have Thread A mark there that it executed 
 and is about to send some response to the client, and query via thread B if this thread was executed. 
If you want thread B to wait until thread A, you can use some locking object, maybe [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), , as suggested by @Wyzard